# Class does not name a type in bison

Tags: c++, bison

This is the beginning of the parser.ypp file

```
%{
    #include <iostream>
    #include "hw3_output.hpp"   
    using namespace std;
    using namespace output;
    extern int yylineno;
    extern int yylex();
    int yyparse();
    void output::errorSyn(int lineno);
    void yyerror(char const* s);
    output::TableStack* SymboleTableStack = new output::TableStack();
    SymboleTableStack->makeTable();
    output::offsetStack* st = new output::offsetStack();
    st->push(0);
%}
```

This is my hw3_output.hpp file. I'm only showing the important parts:

```
    namespace output{
    class SymbolTable {
            vector<std::shared_ptr<SymbolNode>> Symbols;
        public:
            SymbolTable() : Symbols() {}
            void AddSymbolToTable(std::shared_ptr<SymbolNode> symbolNode) {
                Symbols.push_back(symbolNode);
            }
    ....
class TableStack {
    public:
        vector<SymbolTable*> stack;
        TableStack() :stack() {}
        SymbolTable* topTable()
        {
            return *(stack.begin() + stack.size() - 1);
        }
    class offsetStack
        {
        public:
            vector<int> stack;
            offsetStack() :stack() {}

        };
    }

I keep getting the following error (and the same for the offsetStack)
```

[image: na]

Comment: You are declaring `SymboleTableStack` to be a pointer to a type `TableStack` that does not exist in your `output` namespace. Did you mean to declare `SymboleTableStack` as a `output::SymbolTable*` or `output::offsetStack*` instead?

Comment: No actually, I have another struct that I didn't include above. I'll edit.@RemyLebeau

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code which you pasted is at the top-level of the generated file (which makes it possible to use `#include` directives, for example). Recall that the top-level of a C++ program can only contain declarations and definitions, not executable statements. And

```
SymboleTableStack->makeTable();
```

and

```
st->push(0);
```

are executable statements.

You need to do that initialisation inside some function or constructor.

Comment: Can I call the function in the top level section?

Comment: @Yasmin12. No. This has nothing to do with Bison. It's the way C++ works. A C++ program consists of declarations and definitions, nothing else. Anything you want to actually do needs to be inside a function or method. C++ at least lets you put initialisation code inside constructors, so you can get it to happen by constructing an object. Although there are also reasons why many people do not consider that good style. Hopefully you have a good C++ introductory textbook handy.